# GridFS throws Command listIndexes failed exception when uploading file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am unable to get GridFS working on my computer. I am using .Net nuget MongoDb.Driver and I am trying to upload file to mongodb like this:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient();
IMongoDatabase dtb = client.GetDatabase("test");
GridFSBucket bucket = new GridFSBucket(dtb);
using (var stream = File.Open(@"<path>", FileMode.Open))
{
    ObjectId id = bucket.UploadFromStream("data", stream);
    var data = bucket.DownloadAsBytes(id);}
```

But if fails with exception: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command listIndexes failed: ns does not exist: test.ts.files"

The same code works on other computer, fails on my computer. I even reinstalled the mongo with total cleanup. Weirdly the same function worked at first, then only for one specific database and after few tests nothing works.

I am sorry that I cannot provide any more information.

Comment: Have you figured out a way to fix this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most mongo operations will automatically create collections as needed, but some operations don't. The error message `ns does not exist: test.ts.files` implies that the namespace (database + collection) doesn't yet exist & needs to be created beforehand (presumably, that's why it's working on one computer but not another -- I bet if you looked at the `test` database on the working computer, you'd see that the `ts.files` collection exists, and I believe that different versions of mongo automatically create collections at slightly different times).

The [grid fs spec](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/gridfs/gridfs-spec.rst) says that when drivers first attempt to upload a file, they should first ensure that the appropriate indexes exist (that's the point at which this is erroring). Creating the necessary `fs.files` and `fs.chunks` collections manually *should* get this code working, but I'm a little surprised that the driver doesn't handle this for you.